# Laptop display automaticaly changes brightness, despite all options being set to not do it

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, display, brightness

I'm on ACER laptop (v3-371 with Intel HD Graphics 5500), running Windows 10. The issue I'm struggling with is the screen brightness that keeps automaticaly adjusting when I'm running on battery. I've done a lot research but I'm still unable to fix the problem. Here is the list of the things I've done so far:

- Disabled "Display Power Saving Technology" in INTEL Graphics Control Power
- Disabled "Adaptive screen brightness" in Windows Advanced Power Options
- Uninstalled and re-installed the latest Intel HD Graphics drivers from the
  ACER site (I was unable to install the drivers downloaded directly from the INTEL site - the install dialog box told me that I need to get my drivers from the laptop manufacturer's site)

Answer (score 0):

Check BIOS/UEFI settings...There's probably something in there along the lines of "Adaptive Display Brightness" or "Adaptive Display Dimness" or some equivalent lenghty way of saying "auto-dimming".

I don't have any Acers here, so here's the abbreviated version:

1. do a complete shutdown(look up Win 8/Win 10's "hybrid shutdown" if that doesn't mean anything to you).
2. get into BIOS/UEFI settings (some variant on repeatedly tapping a key when you power on, usually one of F1/F2/Del/Esc)
3. find something in the settings that mentions Brightness/Dimness and turn it off
4. save and reboot

Comment: I`ve accessed BIOS and have gone over it pretty thoroughly. I've found absolutely nothing along the lines of adaptive display brightness. I'm pretty sure I've checked every bios tab and every setting. The issue must be somewhere else.